PREPROCESSOR to create an object of a structure with a member array
I have a datatype state_t contains members as shown below:
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t id;
    uint8_t * allowed_transitions;
    bool status;
} state_t;

Now, I would like to define a macro, as below, for creating many states.
#define transitionArgs(...) __VA_ARGS__

/**@brief   Macro for defining a states.
 *
 * @param   _name               Name of the instance.
 * @param   _id                 Identifier value integer
 * @param   _transitions    Allowed transitions set of integers
 */

#define STATE_DEF(_name, _id, _transitions)               \
static state_t _name =                                    \
{                                                         \
   .id = _id;                                             \
   .allowed_transitions = {transitionArgs _transitions};  \
   .status = false;                                       \
}                                                         \

When, I try to define state like here below:
#define STATE_DEF(sleep, 0, (0, 1, 2))

I get the following error: invalid token in macro parameter list
Any insight to the problem is very much appreciated.
Thanks

When you are trying to "execute" a macro, you are actually redefining it. Remove #define and add trailing semicolon ;:
STATE_DEF(sleep, 0, (0, 1, 2));

Second issue is that there are semicolons instead of commas separating items in the initializer:
.id = _id;

should be
.id = _id,

Third issue is that your attempt at initializing pointer with an array doesn't work. I believe what happens is that value 0 is converted into address which is stored to allowed_transitions, while 1 and 2 are unused.
Following line
.allowed_transitions = {transitionArgs _transitions},

should be
.allowed_transitions = (uint8_t[]){transitionArgs _transitions},

to actually create an array, and use it to initialize the pointer.
